# PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest error with Go Daddy API

Tags: api, powershell, godaddy-api

Following a script [(from here)](https://github.com/markafox/GoDaddy_Powershell_DDNS) that many others have suggested works OK, I am having an error that is just outside my ability to understand.  I am novice-to-intermediate with Power Shell and just beginning with API's.

The script is:

```
$domain = 'example.com'                    # your domain
$name = 'xyz'                              # name of the A record to update
$key = 'myKey                              # key for godaddy developer API
$secret = 'mySecret'                       # Secret for godday developer API

$headers = @{}
$headers["Authorization"] = 'sso-key ' + $key + ':' + $secret
$result = Invoke-WebRequest https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/$domain/records/A/$name -method get -headers $headers
$content = ConvertFrom-Json $result.content
$dnsIp = $content.data

# Get public ip address
$currentIp = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip

# THE CODE WORKS FINE UP TO HERE

if ( $currentIp -ne $dnsIp) {
    $Request = @{ttl=3600;data=$currentIp }
    $JSON = Convertto-Json $request

# THE FOLLOWING LINE FAILS WITH THE ERROR NOTED BELOW

    Invoke-WebRequest https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/$domain/records/A/$name -method put -headers $headers -Body $json -ContentType "application/json"
}
```

The following error is returned for the final Invoke-WebRequest:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"code":"INVALID_BODY","fields":[{"code":"UNEXPECTED_TYPE","message":"is not a array","path":"records"}],"message":"Request body doesn't fulfill schema, see details in `fields`"}
At C:\tfsCode\tfs\api.ps1:25 char:5
+     Invoke-WebRequest https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/$domain/reco ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The Go Daddy reference page for [the Get API is here](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/recordGet) and for [the Put API is here](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/recordReplaceTypeName).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PUT API documentation says it’s expecting the body to be an array. This is also what the error message is saying. Try changing this line:

```
$Request = @{ttl=3600;data=$currentIp }
```

to

```
$Request = @(@{ttl=3600;data=$currentIp })
```

@() creates an array in PowerShell, when converted to JSON it will still be an array

@{} creates a hashtable in PowerShell, when converted to JSON it will be an object

Comment: Slightly shorter: `$Request = ,@{ttl=3600;data=$currentIp }` (+1)

Comment: That was subtle, and I deeply appreciate the help.  Worked perfectly.  It makes me wonder how the original code ran for others.